# Why scrapy not giving all the results and the rules part is also not working?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

This script is only providing me with the first result or the `.extract()[0]` if I change 0 to 1 then next item. Why it is not iterating the whole xpath again?

The rule part is also not working. I know the problem is in the `response.xpath`. How to deal with it?

My other script is working but this ain't

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from urlparse import urljoin


class CompItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    data = scrapy.Field()
    name = scrapy.Field()
    date = scrapy.Field()



class criticspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "hand"
    allowed_domains = ["consumercomplaints.in"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.consumercomplaints.in/bysubcategory/mobile-handsets/page/1"]
    rules = (
        Rule(
            SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('"/bysubcategory/mobile-handsets/page/1/+"',)),
            callback="parse_start_url",
            follow=True),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        sites = response.xpath('//table[@width="100%"]')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = CompItem()
            item['date'] = site.xpath('.//td[@class="small"]/text()').extract()[1]
            item['name'] = site.xpath('.//td[@class="small"]//a/text()').extract()[0]
            item['title'] = site.xpath('.//td[@class="complaint"]/h4/a/text()').extract()[0]

            item['link'] = site.xpath('.//td[@class="complaint"]/h4/a/@href').extract()[0]
            if item['link']:
                if 'http://' not in item['link']:
                    item['link'] = urljoin(response.url, item['link'])
                yield scrapy.Request(item['link'],
                                    meta={'item': item},
                                    callback=self.anchor_page)

            items.append(item)

    def anchor_page(self, response):
        old_item = response.request.meta['item']

        old_item['data'] = response.xpath('.//td[@class="compl-text"]/div/text()').extract()
        yield old_item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in how you define `sites`.

Currently, it is just `//table[@width="100%"]` which would result into the complete table to be matched. Instead, find all `div` elements having `id` attribute directly inside a `td` tag:

```
sites = response.xpath("//td/div[@id]")
```

---

As for the `rules` part - here is the approach I would take - use a different from `parse` callback for gathering search results. The complete code with some more improvements:

```
from urlparse import urljoin

import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class CompItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    data = scrapy.Field()
    name = scrapy.Field()
    date = scrapy.Field()



class criticspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "hand"
    allowed_domains = ["consumercomplaints.in"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.consumercomplaints.in/bysubcategory/mobile-handsets"]
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class='pagelinks']"), follow=True, callback="parse_results"),
    )

    def parse_results(self, response):
        sites = response.xpath("//td/div[@id]")
        for site in sites:
            item = CompItem()
            item['date'] = site.xpath('.//td[@class="small"]/text()').extract()[1]
            item['name'] = site.xpath('.//td[@class="small"]//a/text()').extract()[0]
            item['title'] = site.xpath('.//td[@class="complaint"]/h4/a/text()').extract()[0]

            item['link'] = site.xpath('.//td[@class="complaint"]/h4/a/@href').extract()[0]
            if item['link']:
                if 'http://' not in item['link']:
                    item['link'] = urljoin(response.url, item['link'])
                yield scrapy.Request(item['link'],
                                    meta={'item': item},
                                    callback=self.anchor_page)

    def anchor_page(self, response):
        old_item = response.request.meta['item']

        old_item['data'] = response.xpath('.//td[@class="compl-text"]/div/text()').extract()
        yield old_item
```

Comment: Thankyou so much alecxe but what is wrong with my rule part?

Comment: @JohnDene ok, I've updated the answer, check if it works for you.